# how to start a tomcat server in debug mode using terminal in mac system?

Tags: debugging, tomcat

I followed stackoverflow regarding my question but not able to get idea.

export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
and to start server in debug mode:
%TOMCAT_HOME%/bin/catalina.sh jpda start

I did above steps to start tomcat server in debug mode but i am facing issues. Please guide me.

[This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED][1]

Comment: Try `catalina.sh jpda run` to run in foreground or inspect `logs/catalina.out` for observing potential error messages during startup

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot.